# URL Shortener website: Htaccess adding GET request to directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on a URL shortener website and in my htaccess, I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ redirect?code=$1 [NC]
```

This gets the `'CODE'` from the `example.com/CODE` and sends that code to a `redirect.php` file, which redirects to the url that has that code.

I also have a different directory for the user's account; `/account/` to avoid server confusion (so it doesn't think that `example.com/login` should be redirected to a user-specified code from the url shortener).

The only problem is, when I access `example.com/account` it adds `?code=account` to url, like this: `example.com/account?code=account` and I am not entirely sure why.

Can anyone help me? I wish to 'redirect' the `/account` url to `/account/` so it recognizes it as a directory. Or instead of just `account`, have it work with all directories. I have no idea if this is possible or not, thanks regardless.

Comment: You may test adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/account/ before your rule. You also can test the "code" in your PHP code (but it's crappier :) ).

More info on RewriteCond here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: where have you put your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid rewriting for real files and directories like this:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ redirect?code=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this simple url shortener](https://github.com/urigoren/simple_url_shortener), it's very similar to what you are doing.

The core is the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php?short=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And it reads its links dynamically from a json file